# Rewrite rule without changing URL in browser

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want a rewrite rule to work in such a way that it loads the second URL but in browser address field it should show first URL.

For example `domain.com/folder1/folder2` should load `domain.com/folder1` but not show `domain.com/folder/folder2` in browser.

I tried this but it basically changes the URL in browser.

```
RewriteRule ^/folder1/folder2(.*)$ /folder1/$1 [L]
```

Tried googling but didn't get any help. Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 5):

Remove the beginning `/`s from the rule:

```
RewriteRule ^folder1/folder2(.*)$ folder1/$1 [L]
```